# How to install pandas in blender 2.80 python on ubuntu?

Tags: python, pandas, pip, blender

I read that blender comes with its own python version. However I have troubles actually locating it in ubuntu. I had hoped for adding packages there. What is the current way of adding packages, like pandas to blender's python version?

Comment: I'd suggest a more universal skill: How to find out which files were installed by a package and which package installed a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the respective packages to

`/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules`

and restart blender.